# append to existing table in SQL Express does not work

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Hello I have the following code which i'm using to append data tables in SQL server

```
def push_to_sql(sql_table_name, dataframe, sql_conn):
    try:
        dataframe.to_sql(con=sql_conn, name=sql_table_name, if_exists='append', index=False,
                     chunksize=200)
        logger.info("Pushed to the dataframe")
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error(ex)
        logger.warning("Please check SQL connection string or give a valid table name")
```

and below is the connection string format

```
def create_sql_engine(login, password, server_name, db_name, driver_name):
    connection_string = 'mssql+pyodbc://' + login + ':' + password + '@' + server_name + '/' + db_name + '?' + 'driver=' + driver_name
    engine = None
    try:
        engine = create_engine(connection_string)
        logger.info("Connected to the database")
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error(ex)
        logger.warning("Please check the Sql Authentication Parameters")
    return engine
```

Recently i tried this code to push data to SQL Express(I have changed the parameters to the SQL Express), 
the script runs perfectly fine but i cannot see the new data appended in the tables
(there is no error in the log file either).I have all the access to read n write the data in SQL Express. Is there something I missed? Kindly help me.

***** EDIT *****

```
login = 'default'
passw = 'somepassword'
server = 'server.ip\hostname'
db_name = 'TestDB'
driver = 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'

engine = create_sql_engine(login, passw, server, db_name, driver)

if engine is None:
    logger.warning("Cannot insert data as connection was not established")
else:
    if df_from_file is not None:
        push_to_sql('sample_table', df_from_file, engine)
    else:
        logger.warning("Dataframe is empty or File doesn't have valid encoding ")
```

This is sample use case as i cannot reveal any details of connection string, I have validated that n checked it.

Comment: What does the logger report? Do you see *Connected to the database* and *Pushed to the dataframe*? Please show how methods are called.

Comment: @Parfait yes i see the Connected to the database and Pushed to the dataframe.Did you ask about the logger methods? If so then, I use **logger = logging.getLogger()** and  **logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)**

Comment: No, please show how the functions `create_sql_engine` and `push_to_sql` are called with arguments. Your code only defines them. Possibly your *dataframe* is empty.

Comment: @Parfait please check the edit i have added that

Comment: What is *df_from_file*? Show its content. Again it may be empty.